# Noise figure in PSPICE

Tags: noise, simulation, orcad, pspice

There is an example in OrCad PSPICE which calculates noise figure for an RF amplifier.

I know the following formula for noise figure:

$$\text{NF}_\text{dB}=10\log\frac{P_{no}}{G_aP_{ni}}$$

But in this example the software uses another formula:

```
10*Log10(V(inoise)*V(inoise)/8.28e-19)
```

Where V(inoise) is the equivalent  input voltage noise.

I don't understand **why this formula should be true** and **where does 8.28e-19 come from**?
Is it a general formula that can be used in every simulation?

Here is the result
[image]

and the circuit

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where does 8.28e-19 come from?

Thermal noise of a 50 ohm resistor in a 1 Hz bandwidth at 27 degC is 9.1e-10 volts

To convert this to an equivalent power it needs squaring and this produces a number of 8.28e-19.

[Thermal noise calculator](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Thermal-Noise-Calculator.phtml).

The formula also reduces to 20 log\$_{10}(\frac{V_{NOISE}}{9.1e-10}\$) i.e. it compares actual RMS noise against 1Hz-limited voltage noise from a 50 ohm resistor.

Comment: And that 50 ohm resistor is R5 in your circuit, it is the output impedance of your source. So if your output impedance was 100 ohm, you would need a different value !

Comment: @FakeMoustache Is the source required to be matched to use this formula?

Comment: No, a mismatch in source impedance will result in a different gain from input to output. So the noise figure will change but that will be because the output power will be lower (because of the mismatch).